# Prevent Mac Voiceover Screen Reader from announcing programmatically focused element?

Tags: html, wai-aria

```js
var x = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#start-game").click(function(){
   $("#app-focus").attr("tabindex", "-1").focus();
   $("#confirm").text("click confirmation " + x++);
 });
});
```

```css
#app-wrap { position:absolute; left:-9999px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app-wrap" role="application">
  <div id="app-focus" aria-hidden="true"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="start-game" value="begin">
<div id="confirm"></div>
```

I am creating an audio small game that is played on a web page using screen readers.  To make it work I put the focus on an element within a div with role="application" so that I am able to use javascript event handlers etc.

The only problem that I am having is that on Mac Voiceover when focus is set on my element within the div role="application" it announces: *"You are currently on a web application inside of web content. To interact with items in this group, press capslock shift down arrow. To exit this web area, press capslock shift up arrow."*

I need for the screen reader to not announce anything when landing on the application. I've been trying different types of elements, and adding role="presentation", or aria-hidden="true" etc.  I can't seem to get it to stay silent.  Is this impossible? or has anyone else had any luck with Mac VO?

Edit: The application div is located off of the visible page with position:absolute; left:-9999px; there is a div within this application div which I am programmatically focusing on with jQuery after adding tabindex="-1" when the button is pushed to start the game.

Edit:  I've added a snippet which demonstrates this. The announcement is slightly different because the snippet is within a frame but I am seeing the same behavior.  The first time you click the button with Mac Voice Over turned on it will announce information about the element you are on and how to exit it.

EDIT  : Snippet doesn't work on Safari, try on Chrome please. Chrome snippet behaves like Safari on my website.